# Reasons to use parallel dual wound inductors in power converter designs that require a single inductor

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, magnetics

In the AN65 application Note, Jim Williams has used Coiltronics CTX series dual winding inductors/transformers in all of his designs. ([Datasheet Here](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electronic-components/resources/data-sheet/eaton-econo-octa-pac-plus-toroid-power-inductors-transformers-data-sheet.pdf)) The current and inductance varies in the design, but it is always a dual winding inductor used in parallel.

Can it eliminate RF emissions by making it a quadrupole rather than a magnetic dipole, if the windings are counterwound?

Is there a particular advantage to it other than being practical to have different combinations in one component?

[image: CCFL lamp being driven with a Royer Oscillator, modulated by LT1172]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA531.png)
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an65fa.pdf

Comment: It could be because he liked the flexibility of using the coils in series, parallel or as transformers or coupled inductors. Unfortunately, I don't think this is answerable as, sadly, we cannot ask him.

Comment: Worth noting you'd normally increase inductance by putting them in series, not parallel, but with the common core the coils in parallel create the same magnetic field with half the coil resistance (instead of twice).  It can also be used as a common mode choke (or, if you have a use for it, a differential mode choke).

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link for the wound component in question.